# Error CC2061: syntax error: identifier 'GLUquadric'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, identifier

Why does this code give me an error about the identifier `GLUquadric`? As far as I know the GLFW include should bring it into scope.

```
#ifndef BALL_H
#define BALL_H

#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLU
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/ext.hpp>

struct Cuboid;

struct Ball {
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 velocity;
    float radius;

    glm::quat orientation;
    glm::vec3 angular_velocity;

    Ball(float radius);
};

void draw(const Ball& ball, GLUquadric* quadric);
void integrate(Ball& ball, float dt, const Cuboid& platform, glm::vec3 torque);

#endif
```

Comment: Please update your question to show the exact complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution myself. It seems like the .cpp-file that included `Ball.h` (the one I posted) already included `GLFW/glfw3.h` but didn't `#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLU` beforehand. I solved it by adding a define in the .cpp-file, but I suppose that maybe I nicer solution could be done by making my own header, `opengl.h`:

```
#ifndef OPENGL_H
#define OPENGL_H

#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLU
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#endif
```

And then including that instead of `GLFW/glfw3.h`.